# Structured Streaming with Azure Service Bus Topics

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-databricks

How to setup Spark structured streaming session for Azure service bus?
I'm currently using azure databricks as consumer for one of the subscription to Service Bus Topic.

I have looked into couple of things though but seeing issues around it -

https://github.com/elastacloud/servicebusreceiver

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions.md

Comment: what have you tried so far? what issues are you seeing?

Comment: @silent  - with python, I've used **azure 4.0.0** and tried with multiple libraries too.  example :

from azure.servicebus.control_client import ServiceBusService
ImportError: No module named 'azure.servicebus.control_client'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3634229097511669> in <module>()
----> 1 from azure.servicebus.control_client import ServiceBusService

ImportError: No module named 'azure.servicebus.control_client'

Comment: Have you installed the library first? https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/libraries.html#id16

Comment: @silent  - yes. I did. normally I do install libraries whichever I use.

Comment: And also attached them to your cluster? The error looks like the library is not present on the cluster you are using

Comment: @silent - nope. it's attached to the cluster. rechecked it.

Comment: please update your question with your complete code snippet and the error message

Comment: @silent - Deleted and re-created the cluster and used pythonWHL rather PyPi. It worked at the end. But, does databricks have any API connectors for azure ServiceBus Topics apart from EventHubs. I believe, I need to stick sto old school spark streaming rather structured streaming. please correct me, if am wrong

Comment: not that I'm aware of (which doesn't mean that nobody has done it)

Comment: @Shankar Could you provide the python WHL azure package link ?

Comment: @naman1994 -   I don't have access to check that because that application development is long over. But I'm sure I used - " azure-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl "  from https://pypi.org/project/azure/#files